# When does 'Modulepath' shows up in the Libraries tab in 'Java Build Path' under Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have two different computers running both

- Windows 10 x64 and Eclipse Java EE 2020-12.
- Oracle's JDK 11.0.11 x64

On both computers, Eclipse runs with its default configuration, where it is using its built-in JDK, which is JDK 15 (Window > Preferences > Installed JREs).

On both computers, I am importing the same Java Maven project, from the same repository.

On the first computer, when I right-click the project, click `Properties`, select `Java Build Path` on the left side, and open the `Libraries` tab, `JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]` is listed as a root (top level) item under `JARs and class folders on the build path:`. There's another top-level item, `Maven Dependencies`, listed nearby.

When I do the same on the second computer, `JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]` **is listed this time under a** `Modulepath` **top-level item**. `Maven Dependencies` **is listed under a** `Classpath` **top-level item**.

How is that possible? I don't see the difference between the two computers.

The project's pom.xml file contents are here: https://pastebin.com/RQq2DCgF

The parent pom.xml file is here: https://pastebin.com/SKABEEuq

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/296328

Comment: On both computers, try looking within "Installed JREs", on the "Execution Environments" page. Select "JavaSE-1.8" and look at the JREs in the list on the right. If there is not a Java 8 distribution there, but only a Java 9 or newer one, then it's possible that could cause this.  I don't know if this is possible, it's just a hypothesis.